# Extracting value from SOAP/JSON

Tags: php

I have a JSON response, and I have tried many means to extract the value that has (APPROVED), but it is difficult

Here is the Response:

PHP, JSON

```
2028000NGNDepositSecure3D{"lkpTransactionId":"1100037249","lkpErrorNo":"0","lkpErrorDescription":"Approved","lkpEnrolled":"Y","lkpEciFlag":"02","authSend":"Y","authErrorNo":"0","authErrorDescription":"Approved","authCavv":"jHyn+7YFi1EUAREAAAAvNUe6Hv8=","authXid":"O0KGgwbJpRpdB8cw4OUfee34PkA=","authEciFlag":"02","authPAResStatus":"Y"}Successful64086914117475714319752028000052019545301******41541100037249MASTERCARDSamuel Adah00SuccessfultrueSUCCESSFULPAYMENT
```

I would like to get each results in an array or string.

THank you guys.

UPDATE:

I was able to follow your suggestion and I am left with the following results:

```
array(12) {
  ["lkpTransactionId"]=>
  string(10) "1100037249"
  ["lkpErrorNo"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["lkpErrorDescription"]=>
  string(8) "Approved"
  ["lkpEnrolled"]=>
  string(1) "Y"
  ["lkpEciFlag"]=>
  string(2) "02"
  ["authSend"]=>
  string(1) "Y"
  ["authErrorNo"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["authErrorDescription"]=>
  string(8) "Approved"
  ["authCavv"]=>
  string(28) "jHyn+7YFi1EUAREAAAAvNUe6Hv8="
  ["authXid"]=>
  string(28) "O0KGgwbJpRpdB8cw4OUfee34PkA="
  ["authEciFlag"]=>
  string(2) "02"
  ["authPAResStatus"]=>
  string(1) "Y"
}
```

Getting value of authErrorDescription is really difficult for me.

I tried this:

```
foreach($res as $user){ 
      echo $user[8]['authErrorDescription'].'<br/>';
      //echo $user[0]->authErrorDescription;
   }
```

But result did not show properly.

Comment: Be descriptive and try to add the code block you are trying to run along with error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not json in your example. Json starts with {

You can use this code for converting json into php Array

```
$res = json_decode('{"lkpTransactionId":"1100037249","lkpErrorNo":"0","lkpErrorDescription":"Approved","lkpEnrolled":"Y","lkpEciFlag":"02","authSend":"Y","authErrorNo":"0","authErrorDescription":"Approved","authCavv":"jHyn+7YFi1EUAREAAAAvNUe6Hv8=","authXid":"O0KGgwbJpRpdB8cw4OUfee34PkA=","authEciFlag":"02","authPAResStatus":"Y"}',true);

var_dump($res);
```

If you have that response (for any reasons) you have to parse this string before using json_decode. 
`strpos($str,'{')` - will return position of '{' in your string 
`substr` - will return the portion of string that you need.

Eventually you should get somithing like that:

```
$res = json_decode(substr($yourString,strpos($yourString,'{'),strpos($yourString,'}') - strpos($yourString,'{')+1),true);
```

Comment: $res['authErrorDescription'] - use it instead of your 'foreach'